# Serializing two objects which refer to eachother

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm currently working on serializing in C# for the first time and I'm using the XmlSerializer class, but I've come across a problem. I have two classes which refer eachother, and this causes an error when serializing.

The project is a program for class diagram drawing. Each class has a list of the arrows pointing to or from it:

```
public List<UMLArrow> arrowlist;
```

And every arrow has a starting and an ending class:

```
public UMLClass startingClass;
public UMLClass endClass;
```

I figured that when I try to serialize this, I get into an infinite loop because of this problem:

```
<UMLClass>
    <List<UMLArrow> >
        <UMLClass>
            <List<UMLArrow> >
                ...
            <List<UMLArrow> >
        </UMLClass>
    </List<UMLArrow>>
<UMLClass>
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: I suggest you to take a look to this thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815182/circular-reference-when-using-xml-serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` does not support circular references. You need to use a serializer which does. The `DataContractSerializer` (if initialized with `preserveObjectReferences = true`) or the `NetDataContractSerializer` do support it, so you should consider changing the serializer you use.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have implemented your own serialization method. What you need to do to implement serialization of circular dependencies is add an id to each object's representation and keep track of objects serialized. When you serialize an object you check if it was already serialized. If yes, you just serialize a reference to the object, with its id.

Comment: Forgot to mention that i use the XmlSerializer class, main post updated. Is there some way of indicating circular dependency with this class?

Comment: I don't know XmlSerializer, sorry. Check the documentation.