# Circular reference using XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have found a solution for [handling circular reference when using xml serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815182/circular-reference-when-using-xml-serialization). But in my case I have a List:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Items = new List<CategoryItem>();
    }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class CategoryItem
{

    public string Link { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Program:

```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var programmingCategory = new Category {CategoryName = "Programming"};

        var ciProgramming = new CategoryItem
        {
            Link = "www.stackoverflow.com",
            Category = programmingCategory
        };

        var fooCategory = new CategoryItem
        {
            Category = programmingCategory,
            Link = "www.foo.com"
        };
        programmingCategory.Items.Add(ciProgramming);
        programmingCategory.Items.Add(fooCategory);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Category));
        var file = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Create);
        serializer.Serialize(file, programmingCategory);
        file.Close();
    }
```

I always get an

> InvalidOperationException

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your classes must have the [Serializable] attribute on it to make XmlSerializer happy. What is the actual message?

Comment: @AloisKraus IIRC `XmlSerializer` doesn't demands `[Serializable]` attribute

Comment: Hm might be it would help to get the exception message. Adding this attribute is still a good idea since there are Serializers demanding it.

Answer (score 0):

You just change CategoryItem model

```
public class CategoryItem
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Modify this code :

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var programmingCategory = new Category {CategoryName = "Programming"};

        var ciProgramming = new CategoryItem
        {
            Link = "www.stackoverflow.com"
        };

        var fooCategory = new CategoryItem
        {
            Link = "www.foo.com"
        };
        programmingCategory.Items.Add(ciProgramming);
        programmingCategory.Items.Add(fooCategory);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Category));
        var file = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Create);
        serializer.Serialize(file, programmingCategory);
        file.Close();
    }
```

i think it's work fine.Please try this code. I just change your model and get this output.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<Category xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<CategoryName>Programming</CategoryName>


-<Items>


-<CategoryItem>

<Link>www.stackoverflow.com</Link>

</CategoryItem>


-<CategoryItem>

<Link>www.foo.com</Link>

</CategoryItem>

</Items>

</Category>
```