# XML serialize list of objects in list of objects c#

Tags: c#, list, serialization

Good morning, 
My application has an object list. These objects have also had an object list. Here is some code so that you can understand better

```
class Class1
{
    // somes parameters...
    List<Class2> class2s { get; set; }
}

class Class2
{
    // ...
}
```

I would like to serialize Class1, for that I use this code:

```
    public void SaveResources()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(resourcesPath, null);

        Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(resourcesPath);
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<class1>));

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, class1);

        stream.Close();         
    }
```

I would like to point out that the line

> File.WriteAllText(resourcesPath, null);

Is wanted and required for my program

So, as I said, I use this code except that, when my list is empty and I don't add anything to it, my data in my files is well backed up.
As soon as I save my code with objects in the Class1 list, my XML file gets completely empty, and so I lose all the data in it.

So is there a way to serialize an object list that contains an object list?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I just noticed in debug mod that I have an error during serialization:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error during XML document
>   generation'.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Circular reference detected when
>   serializing an object of type Task_Manager__Last_.Project.

Comment: `(typeof(List<class1>))` shouldn't this be uppercase C for class1

Comment: It's a reenactment, the mistake isn't there.

Comment: You have pretty self explanatory error about circular reference. It's hard to predict where is error without details about your classes. Also what is the `class1` object in this line `xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, class1);`, how did you initialize it?

Comment: Search for "XML serialization with circular references"

Comment: The root node of an xml file cannot be an array.  It must be a singleton.  So List<class1> is not valid.  Add another root node around the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular Reference when using XML Serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815182/circular-reference-when-using-xml-serialization)